# Xcode8 something wrong with Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions, apple-push-notifications

My app **DO NOT USE** Push Notification but I got the following email from Apple after uploading to store
[image]

I did not even turn it on
[image]

What should I do now? Please help! This is the first time I've upload app to store

**UPDATE**

My ppplication didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:
[image]

Info.plist[image]

Developer portal [image]

Comment: You are registering apple push notification. Check your app if any popup appears for user permission for Notification Permission remove that code. And on words ios 10 you need to add privacy permission in your info.plist.

Comment: can you show your didfinish launch code

Comment: @ChanWarde Yes I will add it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please see update

Comment: are you used any FCM or any other APNS in your app

Comment: can you show your Plist are you added any privacy permission

Comment: No, I just use Firebase Core and Crash Rerpoting.
I had written some line of code for local push notification then built the project, but I deleted it

Comment: Are you using this method anywhere in your app registerForRemoteNotifications?

Comment: @ĐinhQuangHiếu It clearly shows you have enable push notification in AppID on developer portal but you have to enable in your application. So disable that from developer portal and you are good to go.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani please see **UPDATE**. It was not enabled on developer portal :(

Comment: @jarora nope, I did registerUserNotificationSettings but I deleted these lines.

Comment: @ĐinhQuangHiếu I hope you have double check all this. Check registerUserNotificationSettings in your full project.

Comment: It is just a warning nothing else it will not affect your application submission. Actually from Xcode 8 onwards apple is providing the warning if we don't have enabled push notification in the application. I also received this warning while submitting the application but I ignored it and submitted the application. It was submitted successfully.

Comment: So I need to submit again? @NishantBhindi

Comment: Yes resolve other issues mentioned by apple and submit the build again and it will be submitted successfully..

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani I will double check it right now. And if everything is ok, I will submit again after that :)

Comment: After submiting, Apple give me the same email :(

Comment: Oh it said my delivery was successful :D :D

Comment: Please provide up vote to comments which serves your purpose.@ĐinhQuangHiếu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They said that they are not expecting you to fix APNS issue now but just wanted to make you aware of that. You only need to fix the permission for accessing photos of user. Looks like you've them already added in your info.plist. You can re-submit the binary now.